# Canvas HTML5 and jquery, delete content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

step 1: Draw a segment on canvas

step 2: Delete the contents of the canvas with:

`ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`

step 3: change the values x1, y1 and x2, y2 and draw a new segment.

Problem:  it redraws even the deleted segment?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        $("#Cancella").click(function() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        });

        $("#Esegui").click(function() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var $x1 = $('[name="x1"]').val();
            var $y1 = $('[name="y1"]').val();
            var $x2 = $('[name="x2"]').val();
            var $y2 = $('[name="y2"]').val();
            ctx.moveTo($x1, $y1);
            ctx.lineTo($x2, $y1);
            ctx.stroke();
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000;"></canvas>
    <p>x1:
        <input name="x1" type="text" id="x1" value="10"> y1:
        <input name="y1" type="text" id="y1" value="20">
    </p>
    <p>x2:
        <input name="x2" type="text" id="x2" value="30"> y2:
        <input name="y2" type="text" id="y2" value="40">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="Esegui" id="Esegui" value="Esegui">
        <input type="submit" name="Cancella" id="Cancella" value="Cancella">
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope i helped you Rep was added and removed :/

Answer (score 2):

Use: ctx.beginPath();

The beginPath() method begins a path or resets the current path.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @LeroyThompson's correct answer:

Your `moveTo` plus `lineTo` creates a persistent Path.

All Path commands are remembered so the Path remembers both your old line and your new line.

So when you `stroke` your new line the old (unwanted) line is restroked also.

As Leroy correctly says, **always start out every Path with `ctx.beginPath'**.

`beginPath` does 3 important things:

- The previous Path commands are discarded (so your old line won't redraw!).
- The canvas "Pen" location is reset to the origin coordinate [0,0].
- A new Path is created (ready for new Path commands).